# Not understanding why I'm getting a list index error

Tags: python, list

I'm writing some code to automate some of my b2b email scraping. I have a function, hunter.domain_search(url), that outputs a dictionary with lists as some keys like this

```
{
    'domain': 'turbotitleloan.com',
    'webmail': False,
    'pattern': None,
    'organization': None,
    'emails': [
        {
            'value': 'support@turbotitleloan.com',
            'type': 'generic',
            'confidence': 6,
            'sources': [
                {
                    'domain': 'turbotitleloan.com',
                    'uri': 'http://turbotitleloan.com/car-title-loans/title-loan-faqs',
                    'extracted_on': '2016-06-10'
                },
                {
                    'domain': 'turbotitleloan.com',
                    'uri': 'http://turbotitleloan.com/contact',
                    'extracted_on': '2016-06-10'
                },
                {
                    'domain': 'turbotitleloan.com',
                    'uri': 'http://turbotitleloan.com/faq',
                    'extracted_on': '2015-01-30'
                }
            ],
            'first_name': None,
            'last_name': None,
            'position': None,
            'linkedin': None,
            'twitter': None,
            'phone_number': None
        },
        {
            'value': 'underwriting@turbotitleloan.com',
            'type': 'generic',
            'confidence': 5,
            'sources': [
                {
                    'domain': 'turbotitleloan.com',
                    'uri': 'http://turbotitleloan.com/faq',
                    'extracted_on': '2016-05-02'
                },
                {
                    'domain': 'turbotitleloan.com',
                    'uri': 'http://turbotitleloan.com/car-title-loans/what-to-expect',
                    'extracted_on': '2016-06-10'
                },
                {
                    'domain': 'turbotitleloan.com',
                    'uri': 'http://turbotitleloan.com/car-title-loans/title-loan-faqs',
                    'extracted_on': '2016-06-10'
                }
            ],
            'first_name': None,
            'last_name': None,
            'position': None,
            'linkedin': None,
            'twitter': None,
            'phone_number': None
        }
    ]
}
```

and I want my code to return the values paired with the key 'values', which would just be a series of email addresses. Urls is just a list of domain names. Here's where I think my issue is

```
for url in urls:
    result=hunter.domain_search(url)
    nResult=result['emails']
    nResult[0]['value']
```

It outputs a single email address and then I get a list index out of range error. I'm not getting why I'm encountering this error. Each time it goes through the loop its working with a new list, and all of these lists should have a first element, which is where the dictionary I want to access is stored. So why is my loop working on the first list, and not on subsequent ones?

Comment: `result` is a *list*, and you are trying to index it with a *string*.... if it works sometimes I can only assume it's because `hunter.domain_search` is inconsistent in what it returns.

Answer (score 1):

The index error is probably caused by your function returning a result with an empty `emails` list. Try this to skip entries without emails.

```
for url in urls:
    result=hunter.domain_search(url)
    nResult=result['emails']
    if nResult:
        print(nResult[0]['value'])
    else: 
        print('no emails found in', url)
```